# parse error help with wordpress file

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the portion of code surrounding the issue

```
    function twitter_count($twitter_id, $widget_id, $clear_cache) {

    $twittercount = 0;

    if(get_option('twitter_count_' . $widget_id) == 0 || $clear_cache == 'on' || get_option('twitter_count_api_timer_' . $widget_id) < (time() - 1800)): 
        $followers = $this->curl("http://twitter.com/users/show.xml?screen_name=" . $twitter_id);
        try {
            if($followers):
                $xml = new SimpleXmlElement($followers, LIBXML_NOCDATA);
                if($xml):
                    if((string)$xml->followers_count):
                        $twittercount = (string)$xml->followers_count;
                    endif;
                    update_option('twitter_count_' . $widget_id, $twittercount);
                endif;
            endif;
        } catch(Exception $ex) {}
        update_option('twitter_count_api_timer_' . $widget_id, time());
    else:
        $twittercount = get_option('twitter_count_' . $widget_id);
    endif;

    return $twittercount;

}
```

I am getting this error :
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /home/content/b/r/i/brikrihen/html/brianhenry.com/wordpress/wp-content/themes/StandardTheme_25/lib/followcount.php on line 137

I remove the '{' and still get an error.

I can't figure it out.

Comment: Which line does it complain on?

Comment: which line would be 137?

Comment: `catch(Exception $ex) {}` classic Wordpress ;-)

Comment: on the line that begins:    try {

Comment: actually that is the only code on line 137

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are using an old version of PHP (e.g. PHP 4), which doesn't support `try`/`catch` yet. For PHP that's a `T_STRING` followed by a `'{'` and this will obviously yield a parse error.

Comment: That was my suspicion...

Comment: @Keith: Force you hoster to upgrade to PHP 5.2 oder PHP 5.3. PHP 4 is *really*, *really* outdated.